# Lock in static methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety

Please consider this code:

```
public static class SomeClass
{
    private static List<Item> Items;

    //Constructor

    public static void AddToChache(string key, object item)
    {
        Items.Add(new Item(){ key = key , content = item, DateAdded = DateTime.Now});
    }

    public static List<Item> GetAllItems()
    {
        return Items;
    } 

    ....
```

If I want to create a cache in application level, does this methods need `lock` to handle concurrency?

I want to thread-safe methods.

Comment: Might be better idea to just use existing cache (like MemoryCache) rather than implementing your own (especially using a `List` and not even `Dictionary`).

Comment: Just to reiterate comment by [itsme86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141432/itsme86) from your other related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944037/is-lock-object-deparatly-necessary-for-every-static-methods?noredirect=1) "If this is supposed to be thread-safe, you should never return the actual Items collection. Once it's returned, the collection can be modified while the caller is using it. If you must return all items, return a copy of the collection instead. And yes, that copy operation would have to be locked."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I want to create a cache in application level, does this methods need lock to handle concurrency?

No, if you use a thread safe collection instead, e.g. [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx), otherwise yes - it does.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is I forgot DateTime property.  I have more than 2 property so in this case I can't use dictionary